# MySQL complex indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'd like to ask 2 questions about indexes in MySQL:
**1.** is it possible to have index of type *HASH in MyISAM* engine?
**2.** is it possible to create index on computed value like e.g.

```
CREATE INDEX AD_MAIN_CATEGORY ON ad ((category_id % 100) ASC) USING BTREE;
```

I've got query that selects all categories and counts number of ads in main/sub categories. Each ad has only subcategory_id from which main_category_id can be computed (subcategory_id = 120 => main_category_id = 100). The evil (slow) query:

```
SELECT `c`.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ad WHERE IF(c.parent_id = 0,(ad.category_id DIV 100) * 100 = c.id,ad.category_id=c.id)) AS `count`, `ct`.`label` FROM `category` AS `c` INNER JOIN `category_translation` AS `ct` ON c.id = ct.category_id WHERE (ct.language_id = 1) ORDER BY `c`.`id` ASC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1:

No, see another question about it: [Why does MySQL not have hash indices on MyISAM or InnoDB?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2817/why-does-mysql-not-have-hash-indices-on-myisam-or-innodb)

---

Question 2:

Yes and No. **No**, you cannot in (mainstream) MySQL but **yes**, you can on MariaDB, (a fork or MySQL). Read about: [**Virtual columns**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2817/why-does-mysql-not-have-hash-indices-on-myisam-or-innodb)